# How to convert the firebase timestamp using angular date pipe

Tags: angular, firebase

I am trying to display some firebase timestamp in the template view, Unfortunately no luck with the angular datePipe.

```
<p>Seen {{user.updatedAt | date: 'yyyy/MM/dd h:mm:ss a'}}</p>
```

I do get this error:

```
     ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 
'Unable to convert "Timestamp(seconds=1528515928, nanoseconds=105000000)" 
into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can either convert Timestamp to milliseconds or to Date:

```
<p>Seen {{user.updatedAt.toMillis() | date:'yyyy/MM/dd h:mm:ss a'}}</p>
```

or

```
<p>Seen {{user.updatedAt.toDate() | date:'yyyy/MM/dd h:mm:ss a'}}</p>
```

Comment: Perfect answer! Thanks

Answer (score 31):

Try this `{{ user.updatedAt.seconds * 1000 | date:'MM-dd-yyyy' }}`, the timestamp has a seconds property so you need to access it and then do the multiplication and the pipe. Hope it works for your case.

Answer (score 15):

I use simple custom pipe in Angular. It takes into account LOCALE_ID and you can also use all DatePipe formats:

```
import {formatDate} from '@angular/common';
import {Inject, LOCALE_ID, Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import Timestamp = firebase.firestore.Timestamp;

@Pipe({
    name: 'firestoreDate'
})
export class FirestoreDatePipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) private locale: string) {
    }

    transform(timestamp: Timestamp, format?: string): string {
        if (!timestamp?.toDate) {
            return;
        }
        return formatDate(timestamp.toDate(), format || 'medium', this.locale);
    }
}
```

Tested in Angular 7 - 15.

Answer (score 10):

You can capture all Timestamp property in your service and convert all to date.

For example:

```
import { firestore } from 'firebase/app';
import Timestamp = firestore.Timestamp;

// for Angular 11 use:
// import firebase from 'firebase'; 
// import Timestamp = firebase.firestore.Timestamp; 

@Injectable()
export class YourService {

....

    list = (): Observable<any[]> => this.collection
        .snapshotChanges()
        .pipe(
            map(changes => {
                return changes.map(a => {
                    const data = a.payload.doc.data() as any;
                    Object.keys(data).filter(key => data[key] instanceof Timestamp)
                        .forEach(key => data[key] = data[key].toDate())
                    data._id = a.payload.doc.id;
                    return data;
                });
            })
        );

...
}
```

Comment: This is a much more elegant solution for standard Firestore implementations, IMO.

Comment: Very nice, that you so much !

Comment: Thank you for this nice solution!
import { firestore } from 'firebase/app'; and the Timestamp import failed for me. I found this to work in its place:
**import firebase from 'firebase';
import Timestamp = firebase.firestore.Timestamp;**

Answer (score 5):

The  time shown is timestamp and not actual date. you need to multiply the time by 1000.

```
<p>Seen {{user.updatedAt * 1000 | date:'MM-dd-yyyy'}}</p>
```

Comment: Tried that but nothing shows in the template and no error is logged.

Comment: There is an extraneous pipe / typo in your answer - `{{user.updatedAt * 1000 | date:'MM-dd-yyyy'}}`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of 
`yourDate: Date` 
use 
`yourDate: Timestamp` from `'@firebase/firestore-types';`

[read](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Settings)

Answer (score 3):

the Date pipe will take a number of milliseconds since UTC epoch.  https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe. The Firebase Timestamp provides seconds and fractions of seconds in UTC Epoch time. I use...

```js
new Date(0).setUTCSeconds(YOURFIREBASEDOC.updatedAt['seconds'])
```

Comment: I changed it to:

new Date(0).setUTCSeconds(FIREBASEDATETIME['seconds'])

This is working.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you get the `timestamp` from firebase `updatedAt` values receive as the following format,

```
updatedAt: {seconds: 1635071447, nanoseconds: 950000000}
```

Then, Simply you can pass it to the pipe using the following method,

```
<p>Seen {{user.updatedAt["seconds"] * 1000 | date: 'yyyy/MM/dd h:mm:ss a'}}</p>
```

[For more](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.Timestamp),

> **Parameters**
> **seconds**: number
> The number of seconds of UTC time since
> Unix epoch 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. Must be from 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z to
> 9999-12-31T23:59:59Z inclusive.
>
> **nanoseconds**: number
> The non-negative fractions of a second at
> nanosecond resolution. Negative second values with fractions must
> still have non-negative nanoseconds values that count forward in time.
> Must be from 0 to 999,999,999 inclusive.

Comment: The `updatedAt["seconds"] * 1000` works, while `updatedAt["seconds"]` shows the year as 1970! But why the hell is this so? Why the 1000 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

Take updatedAt:any in you Model.

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

export class class1 implements OnInit {

    constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) { }

    youMethod() {
        let aNewDate = this.datePipe.transform(user.updatedAt.toDate(),"medium");
        console.log(aNewDate)
        // This will print in format  Jun 5, 2018, 5:45:31 PM
   }

}
```

You can used any date format in place ('medium') for display you date variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use date filter but personally I transform dates at the time of fetching using **rxjs map pipe**

```
this.afs.collection('users')
  .valueChanges()
  .pipe(map(
    (users: any[]) => users.map(user => ( {...user, date: user.updatedAt.toDate()} ))
  ))
  .subscribe(result => {
    console.log('result: ', result);
  })
```